# Need to use opaque or transparent colors on stacked histogram & add legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I would like to make the colors on my histogram opaque and I want to add a legend to the graph. I've seen alot of resources for this however I am using the groupby method on my histogram. I'm not sure how to add colors to each of the factors on the groupby

```
sia_table.groupby('subreddit')['sia_compound'].hist(bins = 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an axis using `subplots` then map your plot to it.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,4))
sia_table.groupby('subreddit')['sia_compound'].hist(alpha=0.5, ax=ax)
ax.legend(sia_table['subreddit'].unique())
plt.show()
```